# npm version in package.json is different from what is showing when running npm -v?

Tags: node.js, npm

My npm version in `package.json` file is different than the current version. Any idea how to unite them or is this normal behaviour?

```json
"dependencies": {
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "client": "file:client",
  "config": "^3.3.6",
  "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "firebase": "^9.6.7",
  "npm": "^8.1.4",
  "ts-node": "^10.5.0",
  "typescript": "^4.4.4"
},
```

Running the `npm -v` command returns `8.5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't update is because you aren't updating `npm` globally.

So, the `npm` dependency is redundant.

---

Normally, you would use the following command to update `npm` globally.

```
$ npm install -g npm
```

But, as you are only specifying it in the local project dependencies, it won't update `npm` globally.

---

If you want to update `npm` globally, you can do so with a script in `package.json`, as shown below.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "global": "npm install -g npm@8.1.4"
  }
}
```

You can then call it with the following command.

```
$ npm run global
```

This will update the `npm` version globally.

---

In summary, it is expected behaviour with the way you are doing it currently, but you can update `npm` globally with a script.